# Query to inner join two tables

Tags: mysql

Below I have created three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    EMPLOYEE_ID [int] identity (1,1) not null,
    FIRSTNAME [nvarchar] (20) not null,
    LASTNAME [nvarchar] (20) not null, 
);

CREATE TABLE LEAVE(
    LEAVE_ID [int] identity (1,1) not null,
    START_DATE [DATE]  not null,
    END_DATE [DATE]  not null,
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_LEAVE(
    ELEAVE_ID [int] identity (1,1) not null,
    LEAVE_ID [int] not null,
    EMPLOYEE_ID [int] not null,
);
```

I'm trying to create a query that shows all the employees leave dates.

```
CREATE VIEW [VW_CURRENT_LEAVE]
AS
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
    E.FIRSTNAME, 
    E.LASTNAME, 
    L.START_DATE, 
    L.END_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE E, 
    LEAVE L, 
    EMPLOYEE_LEAVE EL
WHERE   E.EMPLOYEE_ID = EL.E.EMPLOYEE_ID
AND EL.LEAVE_ID = L.LEAVE_ID
AND L.END_DATE >= GETDATE()
AND L.START_DATE <= GETDATE()

GO
```

But the query just returns everything as null. The titles are as I want them but how come it's not filling the information?

[image]

Comment: This is T-SQL so you should tag your question with 'SQL Server' instead of 'MySQL'. Also, have you checked that the data in your three tables has leave periods that span `GETDATE()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get rid of those commas in the `FROM` clause.  This style of table join has been officially deprecated since the ANSI-92 standard, for reasons including that it makes it difficult to even figure out what the actual join criteria is.

Try this query:

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       E.FIRSTNAME,
       E.LASTNAME,
       L.START_DATE,
       L.END_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_LEAVE EL
    ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = EL.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN LEAVE L
    ON EL.LEAVE_ID = L.LEAVE_ID
```

See what this returns, and if it looks good you can try adding the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE L.END_DATE >= GETDATE() AND
      L.START_DATE <= GETDATE()
```

If adding the `WHERE` clause causes no records to be returned you should check to makes sure that any employees have active leave scheduled.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Thanks for the correction.  It is either the data, the join, the `WHERE` clause, or some combination of all 3.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim, but its still returning null values

Comment: Does the query _without_ any `WHERE` condition return any records?

Comment: I took out     where    and still all null in columns

Comment: @Jane have you actually checked there is data in these tables? Can you show us sample data and/or what you are expecting your query to return?

Comment: @Jane Do this: `SELECT E.* FROM EMPLOYEE E` ... do you get any records back?

Comment: SELECT  E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
      E.FIRSTNAME, 
      E.LASTNAME,
      L.START_DATE,
      L.END_DATE
    FROM EMPLOYEE E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_LEAVE EL
    ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = EL.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LEAVE L 
    ON L.LEAVE_ID = EL.LEAVE_ID
                                                                                                                                 i used outer join and now i get results in employee_id, firstname and lastname but still get null values in start and end dates.

Comment: i tried                                                                                                       WHERE L.END_DATE >= GETDATE() AND
      L.[START_DATE] <= GETDATE()                                                               But i still get nothing

Comment: This implies that no employees have leave which match the criteria.